# prevent return type deduction of lambda

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, return-type-deduction

The code below is not compilable due of auto deduction of the type returned from lambda.

what is a correct way to prevent this deduction in C++14 syntax terms without trailing type?

compilation error is about incompatible type (rvalue) on test() input which expects non-const reference

```
struct B {
    int i;
};

struct A {
    B &getB() { return b; }
private:
    B b;
};

void test(B &b)  {
    b.i++;
}

int main() {
    A a;

    test([&a]() { 
        return a.getB();
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I propose you to receive `b` by value: `void test(B b)`

Comment: @SergeyAleksandrovich Note that `test` modifies the original object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems here.

---

First, you don't actually call the lambda, so instead of passing the returned value into `test`, you pass the function object, which is clearly a completely incompatible type! Solve this by adding `()` after the lambda to call it, thereby passing the return value to `test()`.

```
[](){ return 42; } ();
//                 ^^ now the whole expression has value 42
```

---

Secondly, you are right, the deduced return type will be `B`, not `B&`, and the temporary object may not be bound to the ref-to-non-`const` argument of `test(B&)`.

One way around this would be to use a trailing return type to force a reference:

```
    [&a]() -> B& { .... }
```

You seem to know this, but don't want to do it. Why?

Another option is to return a reference wrapper, which is then returned by value but behaves like a reference:

```
return std::ref(a.getB()));
```

---

Another option would be to change `test` to be able to accept some temporary. Since you need this to be able to modify the original object, you could have `test` take a pointer, or other type with reference semantics (a smart pointer, a `std::reference_wrapper<B>`, make `B` have reference semantics when you copy it, ...)

```
void test(B* b) {
    ++(b->i);
}
...
test([&]() { return &a.getB(); } () );
```

Note for pedants: I know the parens in `++(b->i)` aren't strictly necessary. I find it clearer.

Comment: thank you. you are right regarding first . you see - this is not real code but quick sample - so yes my inattention. regarding solutions - to be honest, I hoped on something without code change , probably something with decltype I'm using trailing declaration in the code currently, but thou - maybe there is something else, more modern short clear declaration for such cases....